# Как с помощью CSS отобразить фотографию пользователя?

Tags: css

Вывожу с помощью html-кода в теги li логин пользователя. В каталоге photos хранятся фотки пользователей. Как с помощью CSS отобразить фотографию пользователя?

Comment: Что-то вы написали, понятное только вам. Уточните вопрос, распишите подробнее, приложите пример кода, который вы используете

Comment: Между тегами li вывожу логин пользователя: <li>user1</li> Можно отобразить картинку типа /photos/user1.jpg ?

Comment: Можно, почему нет? <li><img src="/photos/user1.jpg">user1</li>

Comment: а если не использовать тег img? HTML <li>user1</li> оставим... какой должен быть CSS?

Comment: А если не использовать тег img, то куда по-вашему картинка должна вывестись?

Comment: вместо тегов li ... так возможно сделать?

Comment: Вместо тегов li нельзя. Почему вы не хотите добавить img?

Comment: Так стоит задача, чтобы всё рисовать с помощью CSS

Comment: без img? тогда background-image:url('/photos/image.jpg')

Comment: @sitev_ru, Оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Answer (score 1):

Почему-то в комментарияи больше не могу писать, поэтому подытожу, что выяснили с автором топика.
Если вам необходимо вывести картинку (я так понял, что речь идет об аватаре) пользователя, то семантически верно это будет сделано добавлением тега <img>. Если у вас стоит задача "всё рисовать с помощью CSS", то постарайтесь убедить того, кто ее поставил, что такой ход мыслей в корень неверный. Если переубедить не удалось, а из чего следует, что заказчику нравятся нестандартные решения, то можете добавить немного javascript-а.
Алгоритм следующий:

1. Элементу li добавьте аттрибут с названием картинки, например <li data-pic="user1">user1</li>
2. После построения DOM дерева, пробегитесь javascript-ом по элементам списка и обновите свойство background соответствующим путем к картинке.
3. Установите padding-left для li элемента, равный ширине картинки + небольшой отступ для красоты. Если вы уверены, что ширина постоянна, то можно забить в CSS статическое число)

Должно получиться [что-то такое](http://jsfiddle.net/d7hrcutg/1/). Но если и javascript нельзя использовать, то, увы, ваша задача нерешаема.